# For $G=\{\text{upper triangular matrix} \in GL(n,F)\}$, find Z(G)

Tags: group-theory

$G =  \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 & a & b\\0 & 1 & c\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \middle|a,b,c \in F \right\} $
$H =  \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & d\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \middle|d \in F \right\} $ 
**Prove that $Z(G) = H$**. 
I've managed to show that $ H \subseteq Z(G)$, but beside of taking a general matrix $x$, and checking its constraints by demanding $\forall g\in G,\ x=gxg^-1$ by multiplying and comparing the two matrices, I can't see how to finish this. It supposes to be a small "understanding" question, so I doubt if that's the writer's meaning.

Is there any more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix with $a \ne 0$ does not commute with the matrix with $a=b=0$, $c=1$,  whereas a matrix with $c \ne 0$ does not commute with the matrix with $a=1$, $b=c=0$. In both cases, the two products differ in their $(1,3)$ entry.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already know about root subgroups? They are (in your case) given by $E_{12}=\{b=0, c=0\}$, $E_{23}=\{a=0,b=0\}$, $E_{13}=H$. Can you compute the commutator map $[,]: E_{12}\times E_{23}\to G$? Once you have done this, show that each element $g\in G$ can be written as the product $g_{12}g_{23}g_{13}$ where $g_{ij}\in E_{ij}$. Now, check that if, say, $g_{12}\ne 0$ then compute the value of $[g, g_{23}]$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it , and on google I found mostly questions about root subgroups on stackexchange. Does it have an alternative term?